# how to catch header attributes in larave's resource's controller's functions

Tags: php, laravel

I have a resource controller, in which there're 7 functions. (index, create,store, show, edit,update,destroy). Laravel application is just an api. now when user makes a request from front-end, I put a language_id in request's header. **how is it possible to catch this request's header's language_id in laravel's controller's index method which has no parameters passed by default?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a header with:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    $language_id = $request->header('language_id');
}
```

or

```
app('request')->header('language_id');
```

Comment: If I pass $request as parameter, i could also pass $language_id.

Comment: As you can see I wrote two options. The second one doesn't use parameters.

Comment: will the second option be different for each user's request?

Comment: Yes. It get's the information from the http request.